# DOM4J Select Child Nodes

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

I have the tag book, then i read out 2 Nodes

CCUSTBLS_KundennummerBLS

CCOMP_MandantFIBU

After this,i have the Nodes "Lieferadresse". Now i want that i have a loop that iterated through the Node "Lieferadresse". My Problem is that i see evertime all childs form all "Lieferadresse" and not only the childs from first "Lieferadresse". I think my Xpath is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eDoc>
    <book>
        <CCUSTBLS_KundennummerBLS>1143</CCUSTBLS_KundennummerBLS>
        <CCOMP_MandantFIBU>1</CCOMP_MandantFIBU>
        <Lieferadresse>
            <TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse>1</TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse> 
            <TCUSTBLS_Kunde>1143</TCUSTBLS_Kunde>

        </Lieferadresse>
        <Lieferadresse>
            <TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse>2</TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse> 
            <TCUSTBLS_Kunde>1143</TCUSTBLS_Kunde>

        </Lieferadresse>
        <Lieferadresse>
            <TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse>3</TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse> 
            <TCUSTBLS_Kunde>1143</TCUSTBLS_Kunde>

        </Lieferadresse>
    </book>
</eDoc>
```

Java Class

```
List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/eDoc/book/child::*");
    List<Node> list = nodes;

    for (Node node : list) {
        String nodeName = node.getName();

        if("Lieferadresse".equals(nodeName)){
            List<Node> nodesDelivery = document.selectNodes("//"+nodeName+"/child::*");
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
            for(Node nodeDelivery : nodesDelivery){
                System.out.println(nodeDelivery.getName() + " " +nodeDelivery.getText());
            }

        }else{
            System.out.println(nodeName + " " +node.getText());
        }

    }
```

Result:

```
    Root element :eDoc
CCUSTBLS_KundennummerBLS 1143
CCOMP_MandantFIBU 1
------------------------------------------------------
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 1
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 2
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 3
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 1
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 2
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 3
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 1
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 2
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
TSHIPBLS_NrLieferadresse 3
TCUSTBLS_Kunde 1143
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a relative path `*` and call the `selectNodes` method on the `node` variable e.g. `node.selectNodes("*")` (http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Node.html#selectNodes(java.lang.String)). If you know you are interested in child elements you can as well access `node.elements()` (http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html#elements()) if you cast to an `Element` node first..

Comment: Mhm i use now a counter. You think this is ok?`List<Node> nodesLeiferadresse =node.selectNodes("//Lieferadresse["+counterDeliveryAdress+"]");`